# ¿como cambiar de color las pabras en un rich text box?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

**¿como puedo cambiar de color las pabras en un rich text box?**
quiero cambiar de color solo las palabras que esten dentro de mi arreglo, cuanto yo este escribiento en el rich, si llego a escribir una palabra que este dentro de la matriz que ya habia creado, que esta parabla cambie de color.
ejemplo: ***si llego a escribir 'flot', 'ent' o 'doble' que solo esa palabras cambie de color***
A qui esta lo que llevo //declaro la matriz con todas las palabras que voy a utilir//

```
    string[,] palabraReservadas = {
                             {"1","ent","Se utiliza para declarar un entero"},
                             {"2","flot","Se utiliza para declarar un número decimal de 
                              6 a 9 dígitos "},
                             {"3","dec","Se utilizar para declarar un números decimales 
                              de 28 dígitos y de alta precisión"},
                             {"4","doble","se utiliza para números decimales de 15 a 17 
                               dígitos y de mayor precisión"},
                             {"5","car","se utiliza para caracteres individuales"},
                            };
```

//ternimo de llenar mi matriz con todas las palabras que voy a utilir

despues declaro variables para guardar lo que escribo dentro del rich y utilizo un split

```
    string cadena = richTextBox1.Text;
    string[] palabras = cadena.Split();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    var letras = richTextBox1.Controls;
```

ahora solo creo un forech para poder recorrer lo que escribo con lo que tengo en la matriz, meto un for para poder recorrer la matiz y meto un if para poder comprar lo que escribo con lo que tengo en la matriz y si son iguales lo manda a un datagridview

```
    foreach (var PReservada in palabras)
    {
      try
          {
            for (int x = 0; x <= palabraReservadas.GetLength(0)-1; x++)
              {
                 if ( PReservada == palabraReservadas[x, 1])
                   {
                     int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                     dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = palabraReservadas[x, 0];
                     dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = palabraReservadas[x, 1];
                     dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = palabraReservadas[x, 2];
                     //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(palabraReservadas[x, 0], palabraReservadas[x, 1], palabraReservadas[x, 2]);
                            
                   }    
                }
            }
```

Comment: hay muchas cosas que hacer, desde tu split deberias de recorrer tu array y comparar las palabras escritas y separadas por un espacio, ya que si comparas todas se confundiria entre "car" y "caracteres" por ejemplo, esto en un evento del richtexbox quizas keypress o keydonw, ir almacenando todo en variables para luego regresar el texto ya con color a tu richtexbox, dado que no muestras nada de tu codigo para esta actividad solo te puedo describir como me biene a  la logica.